# Do Vlookup on Excel by Java

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

[image: Excel Tables]

Check my Excel Tables SNAP above pasted

By below CODE of java I have read the data and fetch in a arraylist;

```
workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
            ArrayList<String> comps = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
                System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
            }

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    String tempValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    // System.out.println(tempValue);
                    comps.add(tempValue);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < comps.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(comps.get(i));
            }
```

Output is like below after reading and storing into arraylist

```
A
B
1
AA
2
BB
3
CC
```

Now, In first table in my snap, I want to compare Column A to Second Table Column A and when there is a match then in D column of first table I need to put the data of Column B from Second Table. Simply this vlookup between 2 excels. I want to do it by java.

As per my understanding I need to read the first table as well like I did for second table and store it in a Arraylist then start comparing and write it in Column D of first table and save it.

Anyone can help me  with next step? Appreciate the code on this context.

Comment: Why not simply put a `VLOOKUP` formula in column D of first Excel and let Excel do this task?

Comment: @AxelRichter You can assume not a fan of doing manual task and excel.

Comment: If you would read the lookup data into a `Map`, second Excel column A as the key, column B as the value, then the lookup would be as simple as `Map.get(Object key)` for a given key.